# Bootstrap Grid system displaying rows of 6 rather than the desired rows of 3 for large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

May be a newbie question. I am trying to create 2 rows with 3 sections each. But for some reason even when i set class="col-lg-4", the sections still take up boxes like it is class="col-lg-2"
Basically I wanted to have 6 squares inside instead of 6 rectangles

From my understanding, col-lg-4 should take 33% of the container therefore creating a row of 3
I have set it up here but it seems that it does not want to work and I do not have a clue why

```css
.bookshelf {
    background-color: #564E52;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    border: 20px solid #7F5822;
}
@media (max-width: 800px){
    .bookshelf{
        width: 900px;
        height: 500px;
    }
}
#section1 {

    border: 20px solid #7F5822;
}

#section2 {
    border: 20px solid red;
}

#section3 {
    border: 20px solid purple;
}

#section4 {
    border: 20px solid green;
}

#section5 {
    border: 20px solid yellow;
}

#section6 {
    border: 20px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta lang="en-US">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>penpal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="bookshelf">
               
                    
                       <span id="section1" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                       </span>

                       <span id="section2" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                       </span>

                       <span id="section3" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                       </span>

                      <span id="section4" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                      </span>

                       <span id="section5" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                       </span>

                       <span id="section6" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">

                       </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap? For latest version, you need [this HTML structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Use .row class with .bookshelf

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

All columns should be wrapped in an element with class 'row'. Change this:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="bookshelf">
```

Into this:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row bookshelf">
```

> Basically I wanted to have 6 squares inside instead of 6 rectangles

Use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` on your columns to make them square, like this:

```
<span id="section1" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4" style="aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;">
```